# Not Able to Sorting in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to sort data according to `@SortDir` parameter which I am passing to SQL Server. But I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ASC'

Here is my dynamic SQL. I am performing searching on columns dynamically, but I am not able to sort that

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Dsearchsor
    @Name nvarchar(20),
    @Description nvarchar(20),
    @StartIndex int,
    @PageSize int,
    @SortDir nvarchar(20),
    @SortField nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N''
    DECLARE @Select nvarchar(max) = N'
    ;With data AS (Select P.Id,
    P.Name,
    P.Description,
    P.Price,
    P.Prorate,
    B.Name as BillingPeriod,
    P.CreatedDate, 
        CASE '+@SortField+'
                WHEN P.Name THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Name)
            END rn '

    DECLARE @From NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'From Products P '
    DECLARE @WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

    IF @Name IS NOT NULL  
    BEGIN
        SET @WHERE = @WHERE + 'Where P.Name LIKE ''' +'%'+@Name+'%' + ''''
    END

    IF @Description IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF LEN (@Where) > 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND '       
        END

        SET @Where = @Where + 'Description LIKE ''' + +'%'+@Description+'%' + '''' +' )'
    END

    SET @From = @From + ' inner join BillingPeriods B on P.BillingPeriodId = B.Id '
    
    SET @SQL = @Select + @From + @Where +' 
    Select *,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM data) TotalCount From data                    
    order by CASE WHEN '+ @SortDir +' = ASC' +' THEN rn ELSE -rn END    ******This Line Gives Error******
    OFFSET '+(CAST(@StartIndex as varchar(10)))+' ROWS FETCH NEXT '+(CAST(@PageSize as varchar(10)))+' 
    ROWS ONLY'
     
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Help me with this, I am quite new to SQL. Or is there a better way to do this? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Your code is obviously SQL Server, so I added the tag.  When you ask a question about SQL, please add a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for Help.

Comment: In oracle the problem would be that `select *, literal` would not work. Probably you need a prefix for * here too.

Comment: @ThomasStrub I don't think that's the problem here, it works when I remove the Line ```CASE WHEN '+ @SortDir +' = ASC' +' THEN rn ELSE -rn END``` and write just ```rn``` / ```-rn```

Comment: This is dynamic SQL. The first step of debugging dynamic SQL is to print it and inspect it. Don't ever expect to make a big ream of dynamic SQL code and have it work first time

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the Line Which gives error is Printed as                                    
order by CASE WHEN ASC = ASC THEN rn ELSE -rn ENDs

Comment: This is **dangerously** open to SQL Injection! Injecting 2GB of characters into a a dynamic statement is a recipe for disaster!

Comment: You are also injecting you parameters, makinh this **even worse**. This is a security nightmare just waiting to happen. You **need** to get rid of all that unsafe injection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think

```
    order by CASE WHEN '+ @SortDir +' = ASC' +' THEN rn ELSE -rn END    ******This Line Gives Error******
```

gives

```
order by CASE WHEN  = ASC THEN rn ELSE -rn END
```

so you should escape ASC. Probably additionally @SortDir as well

```
    order by CASE WHEN '''+ @SortDir +''' = ''ASC''' +' THEN rn ELSE -rn END
```

Comment: That line Gives                                                                                                          
```order by CASE WHEN ASC = ASC THEN rn ELSE -rn END```

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements.

```
SET @SQL = @Select + @From + @Where + N' 
...
order by rn ' + CASE WHEN UPPER(@SortDir) IN (N'ASC', N'DESC') THEN @SortDir 
  ELSE N'DESC' END 
  + N' OFFSET @StartIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, 
  N'@StartIndex int, @PageSize int', 
  @StartIndex, @PageSize;
```

- Your `ORDER BY` doesn't need a runtime `CASE` expression, and in fact it's almost always going to be better to have that logic outside and generate two different query texts so you get different plans (one direction might be more efficient).
- You should also make sure the string passed into `@SortDir` is one you expect.
- `OFFSET` / `FETCH NEXT` take parameters, so you should pass those explicitly instead of messy string concatenation.
- You should consider changing `@SortField` to `nvarchar(128)` (there is no reason for this to be `max`) and also checking that it contains a valid column name (see the two "protecting yourself" articles below).

Some articles that might be helpful:

- [Pagination with OFFSET / FETCH : A better way](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)
- [#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: Thank you I will keep these points in Mind and Apply, Thanks For help.